# How to test assigning of function to window in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am exporting a class by assigning to the window object so that it can be used on browsers like the code below. However, I am not sure how to test this section of code. Note that I have it built on Travis. 
Could anyone point me to the right direction?

```
class MyClass {
  ...
}    

if (typeof window !== 'undefined'
  && typeof window.MyClass === 'undefined') {
  window.MyClass = MyClass;
}
```

Edit:
I am trying to test if the script is imported in a webpage using puppeteer page.evaluate but it won't increase my test coverage.

Comment: Share what you tried.

Comment: @Evert, I tried puppeteer. gonna try jsdom, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this part of code is not really testable using mocha. One way is test it using mocha, chai and puppeteer but it won't increase istanbul test coverage.

Thus, I would use [istanbul ignore](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md) /* istanbul ignore next */ for this section of code.